# tcolorbox inside strip inserting vertical space where it shoudn't

Tags: tcolorbox, cuted

I have a two column book and I want to have a simple breakable tcolorbox that spans the whole page. However I've found that a lot of vertical space is being inserted where it shouldn't be. Here is a minimal working example.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}\tcbuselibrary{breakable}\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcolorbox{wideframeddbox}[2][]{
    enhanced,  
    breakable,
    before upper={\parindent15pt}

}


\newenvironment{wideframed}{\begin{strip}\begin{wideframeddbox}}{\end{wideframeddbox}\end{strip}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{wideframed}

\lipsum[1-3]
\end{wideframed}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

This results in a large gap between the text on the first page and the beginning of the wideframe, and inside the wideframe there is unnecessary vertical space every couple of lines. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: The core of the problem is that the strip environment puts all material inside a `\vbox` and performs some break algorithm for that box. But, inside a `\vbox`, the break algorithm of `tcolorbox` has to fail ('breakable box inside a breakable box'). Using `break at`, as @Bernard suggested, is a way to replace failing automated breaks by manual breaks.

Comment: Is there a way to make tcolorbox create it's own wide strip? That sounds like a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: I've managed to make some progress by adding `float*` and `width = \textwidth` to `wideframeddbox`. 

This results in a framed box that spans the whole width of the page, but if I put more than a page's worth of text in the box the segment after the break appears in the centre of the next page with no text until the page after that. Rather than at the top of the next page with text below it. 

i.imgur.com/JLd0Sy6.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You can play with the key `break at = some length`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}\tcbuselibrary{breakable}\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\newtcolorbox{wideframeddbox}[2][]{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    before upper={\parindent15pt},
    break at = 25\baselineskip
}

\newenvironment{wideframed}{\begin{strip}\begin{wideframeddbox}}{\end{wideframeddbox}\end{strip}}

\begin{document}
\raggedbottom
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{wideframed}

\lipsum[1-3]
\end{wideframed}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be you could consider to write a `one column` document with some `multicolumn` fragments:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcolorbox{wideframeddbox}[2][]{
    enhanced,  
    breakable,
    before upper={\parindent15pt}

}

%\newenvironment{wideframed}{\begin{strip}\begin{wideframeddbox}}{\end{wideframeddbox}\end{strip}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{multicols}

\begin{wideframeddbox}{}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{wideframeddbox}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[3]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's a very long document with two column for over 95% of the space.

Comment: @BenjaminConfino It was not a solution but a workaround. In any case you should consider that you only need to declare as many `\begin{multicols}{2}...\end{multicols}` environments as wide boxes or one more. May be this little effort compensates all tests with `break at`.